# why else part is not working in android?

Tags: android, if-statement

Even if login_id is null,the condition only executes if part.

---

```
 String login_id = "" ;

    if (login_id != null || login_id != "") {
                url = ONLINE + login_id;
            }else {
                url = direct_url;
            }
```

Comment: Hi,

I think, you are checking null and black string then better option would be like.

    String login_id = "" ;
    
    if (!TextUtil.isEmpty(login_id)) {
        url = ONLINE + login_id;
    }else {
        url = direct_url;
    }

Cheers..!!

Comment: @Chinmay: thanks a lot that is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

**please try this :-**

```
 String login_id = "" ;

    if (login_id != null || !login_id.equals("")) {
                url = ONLINE + login_id;
            }else {
                url = direct_url;
            }
```

becaues **login_id != ""** not working in case of string variable but **!login_id.equal("")** working correctly

Comment: Personally, I think `isEmpty` makes for cleaner code

Comment: @Salah Nour ElDin:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: please try to replace this operator || with &&

Answer (score 0):

just change `login_id.equals("")` or use

```
  if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(login_id)){

  }else{
  }
```

Comment: :Thanks man it helped me a lot..